# Raise exception on shell command failure?

Tags: ruby, exception, shell

I'm writing some scripts in Ruby, and I need to interface with some non-Ruby code via shell commands.  I know there are at least [6 different ways](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html) of executing shell commands from Ruby, unfortunately, none of these seem to stop execution when a shell command fails.

Basically, I'm looking for something that does the equivalent of:

```
set -o errexit
```

...in a Bash script.  Ideally, the solution would raise an exception when the command fails (i.e., by checking for a non-zero return value), maybe with stderr as a message.  This wouldn't be too hard to write, but it seems like this should exist already.  Is there an option that I'm just not finding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way would be to create a new function (or redefine an existing one) to call system() and check the error code.

Something like:

```
old_sys = system

def system(...)
  old_system(...)
  if $? != 0 then raise :some_exception
end
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, this was what I was thinking when I said "wouldn't be too hard to write", but it just seems like something that should have been solved already, you know?  Thanks for the example.

Comment: Although, you'd want to `raise` instead of `throw`

Comment: FYI: The readable alias for `$?` is `$CHILD_STATUS`. Refs: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Process/Status.html, https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html

Answer (score 14):

[Ruby 2.6 adds an `exception:` argument](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#system-has-exception-argument):

```rb
system('ctat nonexistent.txt', exception: true) # Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - ctat)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use one of ruby's special variables. The $? (analogous to the same shell script var).

```
`ls`
if $? == 0
  # Ok to go
else
  # Not ok
end
```

Almost every program sets this var to 0 if everything went fine.

Comment: Why would you use `to_s` to compare with the string `0`?  `if $? == 0`

Comment: I would say even `if $?.zero?`

Comment: @Nakilon ```$?.zero?``` raise NoMethodError

Comment: @Mu-ikJeon, you'll face that if you did not yet call any subprocess, because `$?` is `nil` from the beginning.

Comment: @Nakilon $? is Process::Status class.
```puts $?.class # Process::Status```
The class has no 'zero?' method.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process/Status.html

Comment: @Mu-ikJeon, oh you are right, weird. Seems like the error code is in `$?.exitstatus` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38683399/322020

Comment: The best way to check is `if $?.success?` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process/Status.html#method-i-success-3F. The way I use it is `exit $?.to_i unless $?.success?`

Comment: $?.to_s returns "pid 908 exit 0" when I run it with system("command"), so this doesn't work. However, system("command") and also $?.success? both return true or false depending on whether there was an error.

Answer (score 8):

Tiny bit simpler: you don't need to check `$?` w/ `system`, and since the command you ran will output to `stderr` itself you can usually just non-zero-exit rather than raising an exception w/ an ugly stack-trace:

```
system("<command>") || exit(1)
```

So you could take that a step further and do:

```
(system("<command 1>") &&
  system("<command 2>") &&
  system("<command 3>")) || exit(1)
```

...which would short-circuit and fail on error (in addition to being hard to read).

Ref: From Ruby 2.0 doc for `system` (although true of 1.8.7 as well):

> system returns `true` if the command gives zero exit status, `false` for non zero exit status.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Comment: Interesting, I like this.  Could you add a link to your reference (the part of the Ruby docs where you found this)?