# ruby system command check exit code

Tags: ruby, command, exit, exit-code

I have a bunch of system calls in ruby such as the following and I want to check their exit codes simultaneously so that my script exits out if that command fails.

```
system("VBoxManage createvm --name test1")
system("ruby test.rb")
```

I want something like

`system("VBoxManage createvm --name test1", 0)` <-- where the second parameter checks the exit code and confirms that that system call was successful, and if not, it'll raise an error or do something of that sort.

Is that possible at all?

I've tried something along the lines of this and that didn't work either.

```
system("ruby test.rb")
system("echo $?")
```

or

```
`ruby test.rb`
exit_code = `echo $?`
if exit_code != 0
  raise 'Exit code is not zero'
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching command-line errors using %x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771930/catching-command-line-errors-using-x)

Comment: In the above example, `exit_code` will be a string - either `"0\n"` or `"1\n"`, so `exit_code != 0` will always be true

Answer (score 188, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> system returns `true` if the command gives zero exit status, `false` for
>   non zero exit status. Returns `nil` if command execution fails.

```
system("unknown command")     #=> nil
system("echo foo")            #=> true
system("echo foo | grep bar") #=> false
```

Furthermore

> An error status is available in `$?`.

```
system("VBoxManage createvm --invalid-option")

$?             #=> #<Process::Status: pid 9926 exit 2>
$?.exitstatus  #=> 2
```

Comment: and how to capture its the output (not exit code) to a variable?

Comment: If you are in a rails console, testing this out, just keep in mind you may lose the value of $? so you need to capture it as part of your REPL command

`[10] pry(main)> system("touch /root/test 2> /dev/null")
=> false
[11] pry(main)> $?.exitstatus
=> 0
[12] pry(main)> system("touch /root/test 2> /dev/null"); $?.exitstatus
=> 1`

Comment: Another excellent comparison of `system`, backticks, `%x`, and `exec` provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks

Answer (score 52):

For me, I preferred use `` to call the shell commands and check $? to get process status. The $? is a process status object, you can get the command's process information from this object, including: status code, execution status, pid, etc.

Some useful methods of the $? object:

```
   $?.exitstatus #=> return error code    
   $?.success?   #=> return true if error code is 0, otherwise false
   $?.pid        #=> created process pid
```

Comment: With the help of Rubocop, I found out that the readable alias for `$?` is `$CHILD_STATUS`

Comment: thanks, I had no idea `$?` was a thing in ruby too!

Answer (score 34):

`system` returns `false` if the command has an non-zero exit code, or `nil` if there is no command.

Therefore

```
system( "foo" ) or exit
```

or

```
system( "foo" ) or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
```

should work, and are reasonably concise.

Comment: I liked this technique, super simple

Answer (score 7):

You're not capturing the result of your `system` call, which is where the result code is returned:

```
exit_code = system("ruby test.rb")
```

Remember each `system` call or equivalent, which includes the backtick-method, spawns a new shell, so it's not possible to capture the result of a previous shell's environment. In this case `exit_code` is `true` if everything worked out, `nil` otherwise.

The [`popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) command provides more low-level detail.

Comment: [`Open3.capture3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) is a particularly easy method to use for this sort of task.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to chain them using `and` or `&&`:

```
system("VBoxManage createvm --name test1") and system("ruby test.rb")
```

The second call won't be run if the first fails.

You can wrap those in an `if ()` to give you some flow-control:

```
if (
  system("VBoxManage createvm --name test1") && 
  system("ruby test.rb")
) 
  # do something
else
  # do something with $?
end
```

Comment: This is so far what I want to achieve, straightforward and clear enough. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

[Ruby 2.6 added option to raise exception in Kernel#system](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-6-added-option-to-raise-exception-in-kernel-system):

```
system("command", exception: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want something like
>
> `system("VBoxManage createvm --name test1", 0)` <-- where the second parameter checks the exit code and confirms that that system call was successful, and if not, it'll raise an error or do something of that sort.

You can add `exception: true` to your `system` call to have an error raised on non 0 exit codes.

For example, consider this small wrapper around `system` which prints the command (similar to `bash -x`, fails if there's a non 0 exit code (like `bash -e`) and returns the actual exit code:

```rb
def sys(cmd, *args, **kwargs)
  puts("\e[1m\e[33m#{cmd} #{args}\e[0m\e[22m")
  system(cmd, *args, exception: true, **kwargs)
  return $?.exitstatus
end
```

To be called like: `sys("hg", "update")`
If you want to call a program that uses a different convention for exit codes, you can suppress raising the exception:

```rb
sys("robocopy", src, dst, "/COPYALL", "/E", "/R:0", "/DCOPY:T", exception: false)
```

You can also suppress stdout and stderr for noisy programs:

```rb
sys("hg", "update", "default", :out => File::NULL, :err => File::NULL)
```