# How can an external command return both its output and its exit status to Ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, stdout, exit-code

This is a follow up question regarding [ruby system command check exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728069/ruby-system-command-check-exit-code). I want to run command such that to get its output as well as exit code. Currently what I used in the code is:

```
rv = `#{cmd} 2>&1`
```

But this only captures output, and

```
rv = system(cmd)
```

only captures the exit code. How to achieve both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check `$?.exitstatus` for the exit code.

For more info, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Process/Status.html

Answer (score 3):

Backticks will capture the output from your command. For example, to store the output in the *rv* variable:

```
rv = `echo Error: EX_USAGE; exit 64`
#=> "Error: EX_USAGE\n"
```

You can interrogate the [exit status](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Process/Status.html#method-i-exitstatus) of the process from the built-in *$?* variable or from a [Process::Status](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Process/Status.html) object. For example, to get the exit status of the last backtick command:

```
$?.exitstatus
#=> 64
```

Answer (score 1):

> `$?` accesses the status of the last system executed command if you
>   use the backticks, system() or %{}. You can then access the exitstatus
>   and pid properties.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400/509710)

So you can do `rv = system(cmd)`, and do `status = $?.exitstatus`.