# Using Ruby to call a shell script exit code always returns as 0

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, exit-code

I am using Ruby to call a shell script via:

```
%x[ /root/script.sh -k -m -l -w -p]
exitCode = %x[echo $?]

if exitCode != 0
  do something
else
  do something else
end
```

My problem is the exit code is always equal to 0 even when I force the script to fail. How do I properly get the exit code of the script?

EDIT:
Ok came in this morning and started digging through the script as I could not get an error code of anything besides 0. The script looks something like this...

```
failed() {
      if [ "$1" -ne 0 ] ; then
          echo "$2 failed. INSTALLATION FAILED! Exiting.";
      exit 1;
    fi
}

{

function 1
function 2..
function ..20

} | tee -a logFile.log
```

So the last thing that the script runs is always this log file meaning I never get the real exit code.

Comment: Related: [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby). You can do `exitCode = $?.exitstatus`

Comment: I just tried that, I got a TypeError
    no implicit conversion of Integer into String. 
So I tried doing exitCode = $?.exitstatus.to_i 
I am still getting the same error though

Comment: Interesting. Does `ruby -e '%x[/root/script.sh -k -m -l -w -p]; exitCode=$?.exitstatus; print exitCode'` fail, too?

Comment: You two are on the wrong track. With backticks, the OP's current code contains a String (probably `0`), not an Integer exit status. Call #class on it and see.

Comment: Oh, my intent was to suggest that  `exitCode = %x[echo $?]` should be deleted and  `exitCode = $?.exitstatus` should be added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby system command check exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728069/ruby-system-command-check-exit-code)

Comment: Maybe I should of noted this, I didn't think it mattered but this code is being run through chef. 
I tried the duplicate answer, even when it fails I still get a true and returns 0 for $? and 0 for $?.exitstatus. I am begining to think it may have to do with the script it is over 3,000 lines long and I did not write it. I skimmed through it and it should have an exit code of 1 when it fails but I am left wondering now after trying all these different ways without success.

Comment: In your Ruby code, you create two separate (unrelated) processes one after the other. The first process runs `script.sh`, collects the output, and throws it away (and you better had used `system` with a redirection to `/dev/null` instead of `%x`. The second process consists of a simple `echo $?`. This is the output you are catching. Since `$?` is always 0 when a shell script starts to run, you always get the string '0'  in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Echo *is* True; Inspect Your Last Process Instead

#### What's Wrong

Your current code will almost always evaluate its if-statement as true because `/bin/echo` or the shell builtin `echo` return success unless standard output is closed or some other error occurs. Consider the following Bash snippet:

```sh
echo `false`; echo $? # 0
echo >&-; echo $?     # 1
```

In addition, in your current code, *exitCode* is a String, not an Integer. It's being assigned the standard output of your echo command, so you'd have to call [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) or [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) on it to cast the variable before attempting a valid comparison. For example, consider the following Ruby:

```rb
`echo $?`.class #=> String
"0" == 0        #=> false
"0".to_i == 0   #=> true
```

#### How to Fix the General Case

You need to test the [exit status](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process/Status.html#method-i-exitstatus) directly, or inspect the captured output. For example, in Ruby, you can test the last status of the */bin/false* command with:

```rb
captured_output = `/bin/false`
$?.exitstatus
#=> 1
```

### Fixing Your Specific Example

If you didn't understand anything above, just fix your code by stripping out all the non-essentials. Based on your example, you don't need the interim variable, nor do you actually need to store standard output. Unless you're evaluating specific non-zero exit statuses, you don't even need to inspect the process status directly or even use an equality statement.

Follow the KISS principle, and just evaluate the truthiness of the [Kernel#system](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) call. For example:

```rb
# Just call system if you don't care about the output.
# The result will be true, false, or nil.
if system('/root/script.sh -k -m -l -w -p')
  'clean exit'
else
  "non-zero exit: #{$?}"
end
```

Comment: I still can't seem to get this to work

%x[ /root/script.sh -k -m -l -w -p]
captured_output = 'false'
   puts $?.exitstatus

It still always come back as 0.

Comment: You should **not** use `%x`. Look at the code which CodeGnome provided. The only variation to his code which I would propose, is to do `system('/root/script.sh -k -m -l -w -p  >dev/null')`, because you are not interested in the actual standard output from the script being executed.