# Test that all rspec tests have passed from a ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a ruby file to be run from bash, I want to test that all my `rspec` tests have passed. So I want something like

## test_script.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ls = `rspec spec`
if ls == 'passed' then do something
```

Is there an `rspec` option or some other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rspec`, like a good unix citizen, returns exit code 0 when all was good and a non-zero when there was an error.

You can use `system`, it translates exit codes for you, and returns a boolean-ish value.

```
if system('rspec spec')
  # all good
end
```

Also see this answer for more details: [ruby system command check exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728069/ruby-system-command-check-exit-code)